# Changing background colour but keeping tint for UISwitch "On" state

Tags: swift, uiswitch

Is there any way to change the background color while keeping the grey border when a `UISwitch` is in the "on" state?

By setting:

```
switch.onTintColor = myGreen
```

The switch's border also turns green. But in the off state the background is transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area that is colored with gray, would be the borderColor of the switch's layer. Thus by doing the following, the border will still be the same no matter the state.

```
sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor // sender would be the switch if you where to change the color when the switch value has been changed
```

By default you can add the gray layer by doing this:

```
    let switcher = UISwitch()
    switcher.layer.masksToBounds = true
    switcher.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor // <-- we'll add the gray color
    switcher.layer.borderWidth = 2.0 // controll the width or thickness of the border
    switcher.layer.cornerRadius = 15 // from 15 and up you starting getting that round effect 
    switcher.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 100, height: 40)
    switcher.addTarget(self , action: #selector(didPress), for: .valueChanged)
```

So now every time the switch is turn on and off you can change the color

```
@objc func didPress(sender: UISwitch) {
        switch sender.isOn {
        case true:
            sender.backgroundColor = .green
        case false:
            sender.backgroundColor = .orange
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost solves my issue. The only problem is that setting the backgroundColor to .green in the on state does nothing. Instead setting the onTintColor to .green did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 & Swift 4

```
//On viewDidLoad()
switch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switch_Click), for: .valueChanged)

//add this func
@objc func switch_Click() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = (switch.isOn) ? UIColor.green : UIColor.orange
    self.switch.layer.borderColor = (switch.isOn) ? UIColor.lightGray.cgColor : UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.switch.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.switch.layer.cornerRadius = 16
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 5**, below code worked for me:

```
    // Switch On state
    switchButton.onTintColor = .switchOnColor
    switchButton.setOn(false, animated: true)
    
    // Switch Off state
    switchButton.backgroundColor = .switchOffColor
    switchButton.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
```

Hope will be helping!! :)